# Comparar valores de un input con una base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, login

tengo una duda que espero me puedan resolver, soy nuevo con PHP, uso mas Javascript pero tengo que realizar un pequeño login con PHP y estoy trabado con la comparación de los valores que introduce el usuario 'input' con los valores en la BBDD,

mi código es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y realmente no recuerdo cual es la manera correcta de hacer la comparación, se que se puede usar rowCount o mysql_affected_rows no estoy seguro, si alguien me puede echar una mano? De hecho no se si es así que debería empezar para hacer la comparación

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Edita la pregunta y cambia el código de imagen a texto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método fetchColumn para saber si la consulta ha devuelto False o en este caso si es correcta la aunteticación devolverá 1.

```html
public function autenticarUsuario($datos){
    $smt_aut = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND password=?');
    $smt_aut->execute(array($datos['usuario'],$datos['password']));
    return $smt_aut->fetchColumn();
}
```